# EF - Problem in One To Many Select Query Generated

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I am a EF newbie so bear with me :o

I have a very straight forward relationship in my DB. ts_Order table {ID, OrderDate, OrderNumber} and ts_OrderDetails table {ID, ProductId, OrderID}. ID in both the tables are PK and Identity columns. OrderID in ts_OrderDetails table is FK and refers to ID column of ts_Order table.

I need to select all Orders along with every detail that each order may have. In SQL I will write something like this:

```
select * from ts_Order ORD inner join ts_OrderDetails DTL on ORD.ID=DTL.OrderID
```

Which works perfectly fine.

When I try to do something similar in EF:

```
List<Order> result = context.Orders.Include("OrderDetails").Where(i => i.ID > 0).ToList();
```

This is what is generated by EF:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project1].[OrderDate] AS [OrderDate], 
[Project1].[OrderNumber] AS [OrderNumber], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ID1] AS [ID1], 
[Project1].[Product] AS [Product], 
[Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[OrderDate] AS [OrderDate], 
    [Extent1].[OrderNumber] AS [OrderNumber], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent2].[Product] AS [Product], 
    [Extent2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[ts_Order] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
      [ts_OrderDetails].[ID] AS [ID], 
      [ts_OrderDetails].[Product] AS [Product], 
      [ts_OrderDetails].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
      FROM [dbo].[ts_OrderDetails] AS [ts_OrderDetails]) AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[OrderID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] > 0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Why is the query generated so complicated? Am I missing something?

-Vinod

Comment: What would Linq2Sql make out such a query, better/worse ?

Comment: I have never used LINQ to SQL. May be I should try that! I will let you know what it comes up with.

Comment: Your gonna need to use the [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) in Linq2Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some of the stuff I've seen EF generate that actually is not too bad.  You haven't done anything wrong.

If you would like to get more information on the process EF uses to generate results this is a good read.  Also a good decent guide for making EF as performant as possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx